# SharePoint - Get a list of current users

Tags: sharepoint

What's the best way to get a list of users that are assigned to a SharePoint portal?

Answer (score 22):

It depends on exactly what list of users you want.

All users that exist in a SharePoint web (but don't necessarily have permission):

[SPWeb.AllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allusers.aspx)

Users that exist in a SharePoint web but have been granted some permission:

[SPWeb.Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.users.aspx)

Users that exist in a SharePoint site collection (but don't necessarily have permission):

[SPWeb.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx)

Note: I am assuming you are using WSS 3.0 / MOSS 2007 but this should work for WSS 2.0.

Also look at:

[SPWeb.AllUsers vs. SPWeb.Users](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/marwantarek/archive/2008/11/19/spweb-allusers-vs-spweb-users.aspx)

[SPWeb.AllUsers vs. SPWeb.Users vs. SPWeb.Groups](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/tingfong/archive/2007/08/21/sharepoint-spweb-allusers-vs-spweb-users-vs-spweb-groups.aspx)

Comment: Though it's been a while since this answer was written, I believe these are still valid for SharePoint 2010 and 2013 - please, can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, here's the way that I figured out how to do what I was looking for:

```
Dim Site As New SPSite("SiteURL")
Dim AllUsers As SPUserCollection = Site.RootWeb.AllUsers
Dim u As SPUser
For Each u In AllUsers
    Response.Write(u.LoginName & " " & u.Name & " " & u.Email & "<br />")
Next
```

Comment: you should still award the "answer" to either your own question or to the other answerer - otherwise this question stays open forever ;-)