# Getting a list of site users in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm developing an application on top of Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I'm wondering if it's possible to get all defined users of a certain Sharepoint site? By this I mean getting their IDs (or GUIDs, however they're represented) as well as their human friendly names. So I need any special rights to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329535/sharepoint-get-a-list-of-current-users

Comment: @Rob Windsor: It's not an exact duplicate but it does answer my question as well. Thanks. Add the link as an answer and I'll accept it. I can't just close my own question unless I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic was discussed on this thread:

SharePoint - Get a list of current users
[SharePoint - Get a list of current users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329535/sharepoint-get-a-list-of-current-users)